# How to transfer part of a Xilinx HLS stream to another function?

Tags: c++, templates, xilinx, vivado-hls

I have two variables:

```
void func1(hls::stream<ap_axiu<8,1,1,1>> &a);
void func2(hls::stream<ap_uint<8>> &b);
```

Where `ap_axiu` is defined as:

```
template<int D,int U,int TI,int TD>
  struct ap_axiu{
    ap_uint<D>       data;
    ap_uint<(D+7)/8> keep;
    ap_uint<(D+7)/8> strb;
    ap_uint<U>       user;
    ap_uint<1>       last;
    ap_uint<TI>      id;
    ap_uint<TD>      dest;
  };
```

I would like to call `func2` inside `func1`, using the data of parameter a of `func1` (see defenition of `ap_axiu`). So `func` would look something like this:

```
void func1(hls::stream<ap_axiu<8,1,1,1>> &a) {
   func2(???);
}
```

where `???` should be the `ap_uint<D> data` part of variable `hls::stream<ap_axiu<8,1,1,1>> a`, surrounded by `hls::stream< >`.

How can I do this in C++? I don't have much experience with templates and I also cannot find it on Google.

Comment: Have you read the docs for the library you're using?  https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2020_2/vitis_doc/hls_stream_library.html

Comment: Yes but it does not help me much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void func1(hls::stream<ap_axiu<8,1,1,1>> a)
{
    ap_axiu<8,1,1,1> input = a.read();
    hls::stream<ap_uint<8>> intermediate;
    intermediate.write(input.data);
    func2(intermediate);
}
```

The idea is to read the entire struct from `a` and push the one field you care about into `intermediate` so you can call `func2`.

This assumes you only want to transfer a single element from `func1` to `func2`.  A stream may contain many elements, in which case you may need to add a loop to read and write several values.

Comment: I forgot to mention a and b can either be read or written to. I added reference signs to the a and b variables in the original post. Storing it in an intermediate variable would not work, because I need to transfer a lot of data and there are not enough resources available to store them locally.

Comment: Reference signs won't make any difference: the solution above is the **only possible way ** to go. Afterall, you're synthesizing a FIFO (hls::stream class), and by definition a FIFO has one producer side and one consumer side. In practice, you cannot use the same one to read and write to and from you IP: you need one more argument, so that one stream is only for reading and the other only for writing. If you really need to stay short on ports (or resources) use a BRAM or an AXI interface instead.